# Eliminating else statement on style changes inside function

Tags: javascript

So my attempt to remove the else statement to narrow down some code doesn't seem to be working correctly.

**Here is the code that I have right now**:

```
function formHandler() {
    if (resident !== null) {
        if (resident && (!states.includes(resident.value))) {
            contactFormID.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            contactFormID.style.display = 'block';
        }
        resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
    } else if (is_submitted) {
        contactFormID.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

**Here is an attempt that I'm doing to remove the else statement and toss it on one single line and call an style.display action inside one line**:

```
function formHandler() {
    if (resident !== null) {
        if (resident && (!states.includes(resident.value))) {
            contactFormID.style.display = contactFormID ? 'none' : 'block';
        }
        resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
    } else if (is_submitted) {
        contactFormID.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

What might I be doing wrong? When I have `contactFormID.style.display = contactFormID ? 'none' : 'block';` all of my functionality stops working.

Comment: Just set the style to 'block' before the `if`.

Comment: Like create a new variable and define the style as block and then call the variable?

Comment: something like this? `contactFormID.style.display = resident && states.includes(resident.value) || is_submitted ? 'block' : 'none';` It's not a 100% translation of your initial code, but I guess this is what you could mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```js
function formHandler() {
    contactFormID.style.display = 'block'

    if (resident == null) return 

    if (!states.includes(resident.value))
        contactFormID.style.display = 'none'

    resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
}
```

It appears you only want the display none if `resident` is not null and `resident.value` is contained in the states collection also don't want to add the event listener if resident is null so default it to display block, return if null, and only set it to display none if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your modified code is not running is because of the `if`/`else` statement. You have included the block of code which is inside the `else` block under `if` condition. And due to that, the conversion of `display` to `block` will never happen as the code inside the `if` statement would be skipped when `!stats.includes(resident.value)` is `false`. You can fix it by using the below code

```js
function formHandler() {
  if (resident !== null) {
    var isDisplayNone = !states.includes(resident.value);
    contacctFormID.style.display = isDisplayNone ? 'none' : 'block';
    resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
  } else if (is_submitted) {
    contactFormID.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the first one works, this should work too:

```
function formHandler() {
    if (resident) {
        contactFormID.style.display = states.includes(resident.value)? 'block':'none';
        resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
    } 
    else if (is_submitted) {
        contactFormID.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not supposed to check "resident && (!states.includes(resident.value)" in your one liner if?

```
function formHandler() {
    if (resident !== null) {
            contactFormID.style.display = (resident && 
                  (!states.includes(resident.value)) ? 'none' : 'block';        
        resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
    } else if (is_submitted) {
        contactFormID.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated, I think I used an extra if as well there.

Answer (score 0):

The following code you wrote is not valid, I would suggest reading up on the proper utilization of the ternary operator, and how a ternary operator translates into an equivalent if/else statement:

```
if (resident && (!states.includes(resident.value))) {
    contactFormID.style.display = contactFormID ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

For reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

You can change your code to the following and it should provide your desired result:

```
function formHandler() {
    if (resident !== null) {
        (resident && (!states.includes(resident.value))) ? 
             contactFormID.style.display = 'none' : contactFormID.style.display 
             = 'block';
        resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
    } else if (is_submitted) {
        contactFormID.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: This never set style to `block`, if the condition doesn't pass.

Comment: @Rami, how would I be able to include two items on each side of the ternary operator? Example: `var ? test1 = "" & test1_ext = "" : test1 = "" & test1_ext = ""`

Comment: @Teemu I just fixed the part of code that was erronous you still need the other else if (is_submited) I will post the entire code I intended so it is clear

Comment: @SLE you can simply do something like this:
(condition1 && condition2) ? (a=1, b=2) : (a=2, b=1)

So you can replace the first part with whatever multiple part conditional you want and to set multiple variables you can simply put them in brackets and separate all the variables you want to set with commas.